# What does '$i = new b(); $i->c = "d";' mean in php?

Tags: php, function, variables, new-operator

I have the the following code in a script that I am learning from and I tried echoing or printing the variable thinking it is an array but apparently that doesn't work.

The full code goes something like this

```
$i = new b();

$i->c = "d";
$i->e = "f";
$i->g = "h";
$i->j = "k";
$i->l = "m";
```

I have tried echoing and printing the variable $i but thinking it might be an array but it does not work, while returning a Fatal Error saying that the class 'b' was not found.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php

Comment: +1 while not an interesting question, it's a well described learner question, and attempts to solve yourself have been made. But give `var_dump($i)` or `print_r()` a try next time when `echo` leads to an error or no output.

Comment: @stereofrog: Reading it again, I think it might not actually have. He said there was a Fatal error. But that was caused by the non-existent class. So the echo never executed I suppose. -- That being said, I managed to cause a neverending loop of death with echo once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `new b()` part creates a new instance of class `b`. It would be an object, not an array, if a class named `b` was defined elsewhere in your source code. The other lines assign some strings to properties of that object.

You can read more about object oriented programming in PHP [in the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php).

You might find the [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) function useful in the future.

Answer (score 2):

This code instantiates a new object `$i` from a (apparently non-existent) class `b` and sets several object properties.

Please read the [introduction to Object Oriented Programming](http://php.net/oop) for more.

Answer (score 1):

- `$i = new b();`     Instantiate a new object named `$i` from class `b`
- `$i->c = "d";`       Assign object `$i`'s member c the string value "`d`"